# Update variable on each loop

Tags: c#, winforms

wrote this code which calls Async function once on button click.

But i want it to run continuously updating the Page variable on every loop.

example: 1st loop page = 1 second loop page =2 so on.. and stop the loop on another button click.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
    {

        Page = 2,                
        League = League.BarclaysPremierLeague,
        Nation = Nation.England,
        Position = Position.CentralForward,
        Team = Team.ManchesterUnited

    };

    LoginM.SearchItemsAsync(searchParameters);        
}
```

Sorry for not giving a detailed explanation/
The searchParamters are obtained from textboxes and sent to a Async function on LoginM.cs file by calling :

```
LoginM.SearchItemsAsync(searchParameters);
```

I want LoginM.SearchItemsAsync(searchParameters); to be called continuously and each time it gets called the "Page" variable should be incremented by +1

How do i create a loop to do the above ?

Its a WinForm Project.

Comment: Make pagenumber a global and increment it each click, like so _lastPage++;

Comment: But i want it to get updated automatically on each loop.

Comment: You need to provide more information...

Comment: What "loop"? It seems pretty important so why don't you show us?

Comment: I don't see a loop here ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: What is the project type? Winform, WPF..?

Comment: Its a WinForm Project

the searchParamters are obtained from textboxes and sent to a Async function on LoginM.cs file by calling LoginM.SearchItemsAsync(searchParameters); 

I want LoginM.SearchItemsAsync(searchParameters); to be called continuously and each time it gets called the "Page" variable should be incremented by +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a place to hold your current value, in the example I've made it to be a local named `pageNum`. Inside your loop then, you'll increment that variable and assign it to the `Page` property on the `PlayerSearchParameters` object being constructed in its initializer.

If you want the method to wait for the async method to be completed before starting the next iteration of the loop, make the event handler `async` and `await` the result of the one you're calling.

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pageNum = 0;

    while(true) //<-- Insert whatever your real condition is here instead of true
    {
        var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
        {
            Page = ++pageNum,
            League = League.BarclaysPremierLeague,
            Nation = Nation.England,
            Position = Position.CentralForward,
            Team = Team.ManchesterUnited
        };

        await LoginM.SearchItemsAsync(searchParameters);
     }
}
```

If you're trying to get this behavior without having to click a button first, you could put the body of the method in a handler for the `Load` event on your form instead.